# C - unexpected expression before 'struct'

Tags: c, struct

so i'm getting this "unexpected expression before 'struct'" error when I try to run this. Where it shows in codeblocks is in the main function at the race5k_calc, I left a comment bolded above where it is so you see it easier. Can someone tell me what this error is from?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

#define TEAMS 200
#define RUNNERS 10000
#define LENGTH 20
#define TEAMSIZE 50

struct person {
    char type[4];
    char name[LENGTH];
    int number;
    int age;
    int event;
    float money;
    float time;
};

struct team {
    char name[LENGTH];
    int numbers;
    float money;
    struct person *members;
};

struct person persons[1000];
struct team teams[200];
int per_size=0;
int t_size=0,i=0;

//Function prototypes
void registerPerson(struct person *p, char *name [LENGTH]);
void registerTeam(struct team *t, char * name[LENGTH]);
void race5k_calc(struct person *p, char *name [LENGTH]);
void race10k_calc(struct person *p, char * name [LENGTH]);
void race_marathon_calc(struct person *p, char * name [LENGTH]);
void donation_calc(struct person *p, struct person *members, char *name[LENGTH]);

//Main fucntion
int main() {
    FILE *ifp;
    char type[LENGTH];
    char name [LENGTH];
    int i;
    struct person p,*members;
    struct team t;

    ifp = fopen("input.txt" , "r");
    if(ifp == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return -1;
    }

    while(feof(ifp)!=1){
        if (strcmp(type,"INDV")==0) {
            fread(&p, sizeof(p), 1, ifp);
            registerPerson(&p,&name);
        }

        else if (strcmp(type,"TEAM")==0) {
            fread(&t, sizeof(p), 1, ifp);
            registerTeam(&t,&name);
            members= (struct person *)malloc(t.numbers*sizeof(&p));
            for(i=0;i<t.numbers;i++){
                fread(&p, sizeof(p), 1, ifp);
                members[i]=p;
                registerPerson(&p,&name);
            }

            t.members=members;
        }
    }

//THE NEXT LINE IS WHERE THE ERROR SHOWS UP
    race5k_calc(struct person *p, char *name [LENGTH]); //calling race 5k calcuation
    race10k_calc(struct person *p, char * name [LENGTH]);//calling race 10k calculation
    race_marathon_calc(struct person *p, char * name [LENGTH]);//calling marathon race
    donation_calc(struct person *p, char * name [LENGTH]);//donation calculation.
    break;

    fclose(ifp);

    return 0;
}

void registerPerson(struct person *p, char * name [LENGTH]) {
    if(RUNNERS!=per_size) {
        p->number=per_size;
        (persons)[per_size]=*p;
        per_size=per_size+1;
        printf("%s registerd for the marathon race !",name[ ]);
    }

    else{
        printf("no of members in the team is equal to 1");
    }

    return;
}

void registerTeam(struct team *t, char *name[LENGTH]){
    if(t_size>=5 && t_size<=TEAMSIZE){
        teams[t_size]=*t;
        t_size=t_size+1;
        // COMMENTS
        printf(" %s registered for the team event ,they have been assigned the number %d ",name,t_size);
    }

    else{
        printf("not registerd for team event ");
    }
    return;
}

void race5k_calc(struct person *p, char *name [LENGTH]) {
    int i=0;
    //calculate for individual persons
    for(i=0;i<per_size;i++) {
    //checking whether person event is 5k run and finding the winner
        if(persons[i].event==5){
            for(i=0;i<per_size;i++){
                if(persons[i].time==persons[i+1].time){
                    p=&persons[i+1];
                    printf("5k race: %s has the fastest time with %s minutes", persons[i],persons[i].time);
                }
                else if(persons[i].time<persons[i+1].time){
                    p=&persons[i];
                    printf("5k race: %s has the fastest time with %s minutes", persons[i],persons[i].time);
                }
                else if(persons[i].time>persons[i+1].time){
                    p=&persons[i+1];
                    printf("5k race: %s has the fastest time with %s minutes", persons[i],persons[i].time);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return;
    printf("person is not 5k race winner");
}

void race10k_calc(struct person *p, char * name [LENGTH]){
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<per_size;i++){
        if(persons[i].event==10){
            for(i=0;i<per_size;i++){
                if(persons[i].time==persons[i+1].time) {
                    p=&persons[i+1];
                    printf("10k race: %s has the fastest time with %s minutes", persons[i],persons[i].time);
                }
                else if(persons[i].time<persons[i+1].time) {
                    p=&persons[i];
                    printf("10k race: %s has the fastest time with %s minutes", persons[i],persons[i].time);
                }

                else if(persons[i].time>persons[i+1].time) {
                    p=&persons[i+1];
                    printf("10k race: %s has the fastest time with %s minutes", persons[i],persons[i].time);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("person is not a 10k race winner");
    return;
}

void race_marathon_calc(struct person *p, char * name [LENGTH]){
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<per_size;i++){
        if(persons[i].event==42){
            for(i=0;i<per_size;i++){
                if(persons[i].time==persons[i+1].time) {
                    p=&persons[i+1];
                    //COMMENTS
                }
                else if(persons[i].time<persons[i+1].time) {
                    p=&persons[i];
                    printf("%s qualified in a marthon run with a time of %s" minutes !",persons[i].name,persons[i].time);
                }
                else if(persons[i].time>persons[i+1].time) {
                    p=&persons[i+1];
                    //COMMENTS
                    printf("%s qualified in a marthon run with a time of %s" minutes !",persons[i].name,persons[i].time);
                }
            }
        }
    }
   printf("they have same run-time tie");
    return;
}

void donation_calc(struct person *p, struct person *members, char *name[LENGTH]) {
    float amt=0,t_amt=0,max_amt=0;
    struct team t;
    int i=0,j=0,l;
    for(i=0;i<t_size;i++) {
        t=teams[i];
        members=t.members;
        l=sizeof(members)/sizeof(*members);
        for(j=0;j<l;j++) {
            if(members[j].money>members[j].money) {
                max_amt=members[j].money;
                p=&members[j];
            }
            printf("\n%s -- %.2f",p->name,max_amt);
            t_amt=t_amt+members[j].money;
            printf("\nINDEX - %s ",t.name);
            printf("%s raised the most money in %s with a donation of %s",person[i].name,t.name,t_amt);
        }
    }
    amt=0;
    for(i=0;i<per_size;i++){
        amt+=persons[i].money;
        printf("INDEX: %.2f\n\n", amt);
        printf("the runners raised % 2f maount for charity",amt);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: When passing args to functions, you just need the name: `race5k_calc(&p, name);`

Comment: That's a lot of code. Please learn how to create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also mark out where in the shown code the error is, for example with a comment. And include the *full* and *complete* error output, preferably copy and paste the full build output into the body of the question. Lastly, please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude When I post just the code that pertains to my question people tell me to post all the code, when I post all the code people tell me too use minimal code. I did leave a comment in the code also. If i posted the supposed output then it would longer.

Comment: All the code **neccessary**! That does not mean all the code **you have**. Read the linked pages.

Comment: @MDXF Everything is nicely spaced and indented, not overdue comments everywhere. I thought it looked clean. I thought if I put just the main function people would ask for the full code.

Comment: @element You're right, I apologize, I did not read your code carefully. There are a few minimal improvements to be made but overall you write fairly clean code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call a function, you do not specify the argument types. So, instead, call it as

`race5k_calc(&p,&name);`